# Spring ignore setting log level for specific packages on cloud

Tags: java, spring

I've set log level for package on cloud config:

```
logging:
  level:
    com.hello.controller: DEBUG
```

But it fails with displaying that on cluster. It works only locally.
I checked the properties calling `/actuator/env` endpoint and they are displayed properly:

```
"logging.level.com.hello.controller": {
                    "value": "DEBUG"
                }
```

I use `spring-boot-starter-parent 2.3.12.RELEASE`.

Comment: how about introducing logback lib to your project?

Comment: I also use spring-boot-starter-web dependency and there is logback set. And as I know spring boot uses logback as default.

Comment: You can add logback.xml to your resource file and set logging levels inside

Comment: If you want example I can add fragment of code

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the `logging.level.root` set excludes any package log level change.

EDIT:
This is wrong answer.

Comment: that is not true/how it is designed/documented

Comment: i found: "If you use Spring Boot to configure log settings, you should place this configuration in `bootstrap.[yml | properties]` if you would like it to apply to all events." [here, spring-cloud](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#logging-configuration)

Comment: loggin.level.root works also on cloud config, except for specific packages